# How to call CPUID leaf 7 and subleaf 0?

Tags: cpuid

I have downloaded and installed yum install cpuid on fedora.
Could you please let me know How I can call CPUID leaf 7 and subleaf 0 ? I wanted to check some features available on that platform. 
I really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

_cpuid_count can be used to get function 7 and 0xD with a subleaf.

The definition is in cpuid.h

```
#define __cpuid_count(level, count, a, b, c, d)
    __asm__ ("cpuid\n\t"
             : "=a" (a), "=b" (b), "=c" (c), "=d" (d)
             : "0" (level), "2" (count))
```

Note that _cpuid_count does not check if the function is supported.
You can make a check similar to __get_cpuid in cpuid.h.  This should probably be added to stdc libraries.

```
static __inline int
__get_cpuid_count (unsigned int __level, unsigned int __count,
           unsigned int *__eax, unsigned int *__ebx,
           unsigned int *__ecx, unsigned int *__edx)
{
    unsigned int __ext = __level & 0x80000000;
    if (__get_cpuid_max (__ext, 0) < __level)
        return 0;

    __cpuid_count (__level, __count, *__eax, *__ebx, *__ecx, *__edx);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you can use [`__get_cpuid_max`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/config/i386/cpuid.h) instead. `__get_cpuid_max` performs the necessary checks to ensure the function/leaf is available.

Comment: Why `__level & 0x80000000`?  That looks wrong to me.